# Change property of model that place outside of 'BeginForm'

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc-4

I want change property of model that place outside of @using(BeginForm(...)){} in view page.

my enum :

```
public enum Person
{
    Student = 0,
    Teacher = 1
}
```

my model :

```
public class MyModel
{
    public string FirstName { get;set; }
    public string LastName { get;set; }
    public Person Person { get;set; }
    public string Address {get;set;}
}

my view :

@model MyModel


<span>PersonType : </span>
@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.Person, ViewBage.Person as IEnumerable<SelectListItem>)


@Html.Beginform(...)
{
   @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.FirstName)
   @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.LastName)
}
```

how can write code in view that change Mymodel.Person property in MyModel?
please help me...

Comment: you can just use <%----%> as block and write your c# code.

Comment: I think you should add a hidden field to the form and populate it when a value is chosen on the client side. That way you will be able to access it when the form is submitted.

Comment: How do you expect that data to get back to the server if it's not inside the form? Why can't it be inside the form?